# Dapper map subquery value to property

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to fetch and map data. I've the following query and relevant class.

```
SELECT pinv.* , sp.SupplierId,sp.SupplierName,sp.Contact1,sp.SupplierAddress,ac.AccountId,ac.AccountName, 
(Select Count(*) from ReturnInvoices rinv Where rinv.InvoiceId = pinv.PurchaseInvoiceId) as ReturnInvoicesCount  
FROM PurchaseInvoices pinv  
LEFT JOIN Suppliers sp ON sp.SupplierId = pinv.SupplierId  
LEFT JOIN Accounts ac on ac.AccountId = pinv.AccountId
```

And the class.

```
public class PurchaseInvoice
{
    public int PurchaseInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseInvoiceType { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int ReceiptNumber { get; set; }
    public int ReturnInvoicesCount { get; set; }  // to map ReturnInvoiceCount by SubQuery
    public DateTime PromisedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public decimal InvoiceQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingCharges { get; set; }
    public decimal Surcharge { get; set; }
    public string PaymentMode { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPayment { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountRemaining { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public ProductReceived ProductReceived { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sharing other classes because they are not relevant. Now, if i run above query, I get perfect results as excepted. After fetching results the dapper returns all data just fine but **`ReturnInvoicesCount` is not mapped** (or idk something else is problem). This is how I'm using dapper.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_conString))
{
    var query = QueryHelper.GetPurchaseInvoicesQuery(start, end, simpleSearchText, searchTokensList);
    // ignore above line, just getting query with parameters etc

    var data = await connection.QueryAsync<PurchaseInvoice, Supplier, Account>(query.Query,
        query.queryParams, splitOn: "SupplierId,AccountId");

    return data;
}
```

As i said, I get correct result mapped except field `ReturnInvoicesCount` which is 0. While on server as can be seen `ReturnInvoiceCount` have a value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have splits on `SupplierId` (Maps to `Supplier`) and `AccountId` (Maps to `Account`). The problem is that `ReturnInvoicesCount` is at the wrong column position to be correctly mapped. Currently, you tell dapper that `ReturnInvoicesCount` belongs to Account.

Since `ReturnInvoicesCount` belongs to `PurchaseInvoice` you have to move it before `SupplierId`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much Alex :) exactly that's what i was missing. It's resolved now. Stay blessed